# Issue with Kotlin coroutines and mapping a list in my code

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm encountering an issue with my Kotlin code that uses coroutines. I'm trying to retrieve data using Dao.getSyllabusType("BCA1", "Theory"), map the resulting list and then log each item using Log.d(TAG, "exp: $it"). However, it seems that the code is not working as expected, and I'm not sure what the problem is. It only occurs when I tried to convert flows to a list, simple collet works but I have to map it and extract the list.

Code snippet:

```kotlin
private fun exp() = launchWhenStarted {
    dao.getSyllabusType("BCA1", "Theory")
        .map { list ->
            list.map {
                Pair(it.subject, it.code)
            }
        }.toList().flatten().forEach {
            Log.d(TAG, "exp: $it")
        }
}
```

Dao

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM syllabus_table WHERE openCode LIKE '%'||:query||'%' and type Like '%'||:type||'%' ORDER BY listOrder ASC")
    fun getSyllabusType(query: String, type: String): Flow<List<SyllabusModel>>
```

Comment: "The code does not work as expected" -> What do you expect, and what happened?

Comment: I suspect it hangs in `toList()`, because the flow never completes - it waits for changes to the data forever. Do you need to fetch the data only once or watch it for changes?

Comment: Or the flow pushes a lot of element, and as it wait all elements to be collected, nothing is printed for a very long time. You could start to replace map and to list and flatten with a simpler flatMap and collect combination, to really stream results. And I find strange that your DAO returns a flow of list  instead of a flow of SyllabusModel directly.

Answer (score 0):

A Flow from a Room DAO is infinite because it perpetually monitors the database for changes until you cancel collection. `toList()` is terminal so it will hang (suspend) forever when you call it on an infinite flow.

It's not entirely clear what your expected behavior was, but it looks like you want to iterate every item of each list that is emitted. That could be done like this:

```
private fun exp() = launchWhenStarted {
    dao.getSyllabusType("BCA1", "Theory")
        .map { list ->
            list.map {
                Pair(it.subject, it.code)
            }.onEach {
                Log.d(TAG, "exp: $it")
            }
        }.collect()
}
```

Comment: Isn't this code a no-op? You didn't use any terminal operator here.